# firebase cloud funtions the engine node is incompatible with this module

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, yarnpkg

I've created a firebase cloud functions project which has the following dependencies added by default and the following engines:

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
}
```

Whenever I run `yarn add` I get following error and dependency not added:

```
error firebase-admin@8.4.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0". Got "8.11.4"
```

I then try change node engine version to 10 `"engines": {"node": "10"}`, but now get the following error when I yarn add:

```
error functions@: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "10". Got "8.11.4"
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly does your entire package.json file look like after you tried to satisfy the error message? Please edit the question to show it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a [Github issue](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride/issues/131#issuecomment-253319816) which addressed the problem you are having. To summarize, you can:

- run `yarn config set ignore-engines true`
- Ensure the versions in `node -v` and `npm -v` matches the versions listed in `package.json` and if not, update to match the intended version

Comment: Thanks. "Ensure the versions in `node -v` matches the version listed in `package.json`" solved my problem. I would recommend one does not "edit the package.json accordingly" every time your computer has a different version, and instead update your computer to match the intended version, which worked for me.

Comment: Without setting it in configuration `yarn install --ignore-engines`

Answer (score 2):

Use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) so you can use differents version of node.

---

When installed you can see all available versiosn with:

```
$ nvm ls-remote
    v0.1.14
    v0.1.15
    v0.1.16
    v0.1.17
    v0.1.18
...
   v12.13.1
    v13.0.0
    v13.0.1
    v13.1.0
    v13.2.0
```

Then install the version you need. For example, for version 8:

```
$ nvm i 8
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.16.2/node-v8.16.2-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100,0%
WARNING: checksums are currently disabled for node.js v4.0 and later
Now using node v8.16.2 (npm v6.4.1)
```

Test:

```
$ node -v
v8.16.2
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably you need to add this to your `package.json`

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8" // or "10"
}
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my question. I tried both 8 and 10.